# Linux alternative for windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Is there any Linux alternative for windows 8 or Windows 8.1 operating system?
I want to know if there is a Linux disto which looks exactly as win 8.

Comment: Install Xubuntu 12.04.4, and after that install KDE Plasma Desktop and all Plasma Widgets that you need using Synaptic Package Manager. It will be a real treat, and you'll be able to boot into both XFCE and KDE sessions. Don't go for Ubuntu/Xubuntu 14.04, many driver issues and other issues that you don't want to face.

Comment: its best to ask about other distros at unix.stackexchange.com  If you are interested about how to style Kubuntu etc like windows 8 then that is another question you may wish to consider.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any Linux alternatives that look exactly like Windows 8. However, there is an alternative that is styled similar to Windows 7 with a Windows 8-esque theme, named [ZorinOS](http://zorin-os.com/).

Personally, I would simply recommend trying out the different Ubuntu flavours. Kubuntu (KDE), GNOME Ubuntu (GNOME), and Ubuntu (Unity) are the main highlights.